# 'Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be 'used' flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-remote-config

I have setup firebase config for flutter

According to documentation https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config#-readme-tab-

My key is

[image]

then I have **Published** also then i tried following code and it will return

> 'Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be ''used'

could you please point issue

I have tried those also

[Firebase Remote Config - Initial fetch return local default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328144/firebase-remote-config-initial-fetch-return-local-default-values)

[Remote config in Flutter app throws exception on fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983314/remote-config-in-flutter-app-throws-exception-on-fetch)

```
try {
              remoteConfig.getString('welcome')
              // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
              await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
              await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
     } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
              // Fetch throttled.
              print(exception);
    } catch (exception) {
              print(
                  'Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
                  'used');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it's work for me

```
  FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;

  initializeRemote() async {
    // remoteConfig = await setupRemoteConfig();
    //!- must be active firebase remote config 
    bool updated = await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
    if (updated) {
      print("found");
      // the config has been updated, new parameter values are available.
    } else {
      print("not print");
      // the config values were previously updated.
    }
    await remoteConfig.ensureInitialized().then((value) async {
      print("remote value -> ${await remoteConfig.getString("app_version")}");

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me,

```
    await remoteConfig.ensureInitialized();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android emulator, ensure it has Google play services enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you fight these problems, in the end, everything gets mixed up. I think after the post you could already see the configured value, but the error occurs when querying another parameter name. Add the following line to see the actual error you are getting.

print('EXCEPTION: $exception');

```
try {
      await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
      await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
      String forceUpdateCurrentVersion =
          remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
      double newVersion =
          double.parse(forceUpdateCurrentVersion.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));
      if (newVersion > currentVersion) {
        _showVersionDialog(context);
      }
    } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
      // Fetch throttled.
      print(exception);
    } catch (exception) {
      print('EXCEPTION: $exception');
      print('Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
          'used');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put value don't put braces for Default value

For Example

[image]

Then use below code in flutter

remoteConfig.getString('IT_');